# Asp.net Server tags cannot use <% ...%> structures Error

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, server, tags

I'm dynamically filling Html table content between `<%%>` tags. However, I cannot print any  button property  user information when I want to add a button and delete a record.

[image]

```
<%
foreach (var item in ListUser)
{
%>
<tr>
<th><img src="images/users/5.jpg" alt="user" class="profile-pic" height="40" width="40"/></th>
<th><%=item.fullName%> </th>
<th><%=item.email %></th>
<th><%=item.userType %></th>
<th><%=item.registerDate %></th>
<th><asp:Button ID="btn_deleteUser" class="btn btn-primary"  CommandArgument=<%=item.userId+"" %> Text="Sil"  runat="server"   OnClick="btn_deleteUser_Click"/></th>

<%    
}

%>
```

[image: Error screen]

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Use a Repeater or GridView and bind `ListUser` to it. Then you have ItemTemplate's in which you can place other Controls.

Comment: I didn't use the gridview because there wasn't a lot of big data. Isn't there a method to use a table? Can't we trigger the asp.net function with jquery?

Comment: No. If you want that you need an jquery/ajax only solution.